# Is it possible for a module to know the name of the module or program that has imported it?

Tags: python

```
# module mod1.py
import mod2



# module mod2.py
print("I have been imported by %s" %(whoImportedMe?))
```

we want to print out "mod1"

Comment: What if `mod3` later imports `mod2`?

Comment: The reason for the question is the following: Suppose that you have two modules, modA and modB. They are very different but they share a piece of logic that is identical. It would be nice to remove this shared piece of logic to its own file for any number of good reasons. However, if it is placed into its own module, modC say, then it might be nice that only modA and modB could import it. The code within modC is only valuable to modA and modB and not other modules or programs. If anything other than modA or modB imported modC, it could print an error and exit. Is there another way to do this?